# ASP.net file download is appending html at the end of file after upgrading from windows server 2008 to 2012

Tags: html, asp.net, windows, vb.net, iis

We recently upgraded our main web server to Windows Server 2012 from Windows Server 2008. It seems a side effect because of this upgrade is causing one of our file download pages to append the HTML code to the end of the file.

This is the code we use to push the file to the browser:

```
Context.Response.Buffer = True
                        Context.Response.Clear()
                        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & FileName & """")
                        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", New FileInfo(AmendmentFolder & FileName).Length.ToString())
                        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                        Context.Response.TransmitFile(AmendmentFolder & FileName)
                        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

In this case the files are xlsx files, and if I open them in a text editor I can clearly see the HTML being appended to the end of the file. Now this is odd because the code worked fine (and still does work) on our old server, where it is NOT appending the HTML at the end of the file.

So I'm wondering if something in upgrading the server, like a setting in IIS is potentially causing this problem.

The VB.net code is unchanged.
The same .NET version is being used.

Comment: Maybe flushing and SuppressContent = true will get rid of it.  Good question though, I wonder why 2008 vs 2012 would make a difference.

Comment: What HTML code is it appending ? Something arbitrary or something from layout or a view ?

Comment: It was appending the entirety of output/response of the page. I fixed it by adding a Response.Flush() after the TransmitFile, but I would still like to know why this was required after changing to windows 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same.
Author said that Response.Flush() fixed it, but not in my case because I already used it.

We can add Response.End() (or just change Response.Flush to Response.End) to solve it.